# Elliptic lifting theorem of Laplace-Beltrami Operator.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

We know that the Laplace-Beltrami Operator is widly used in many areas, whose definition can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator). I have learned basic knowledge about PDE and Sobolev spaces, but I  know little about the elliptic lifting theorem of Laplace-Beltrami Operator, which some authors directly used without any detail in their article. So I wonder if any one know something about elliptic lifting theorem of Laplace-Beltrami Operator. I would also be grateful if anyone can provide some books or articles about this theorem.

The part of the original article reads as follows:

> Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded domain with sufficiently smooth boundary and $\psi$ satisfies
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> \Delta \psi=0, \quad \text { in } \Omega, \\
> \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \boldsymbol{n}}=\boldsymbol{E} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}, \quad \text { on } \partial \Omega, \\
> \int_{\Omega} \psi d x=0 .
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> Hence, applying the elliptic lifting theorem for the Laplace-Beltrami operator on smooth surfaces, we have
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &\|\psi\|_{H^{\frac{3}{2}}(\partial \Omega)} \\
> &\leq C \left\|\operatorname{div}_{T} \nabla_{T} \psi\right\|_{H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)}+C  \left|\int_{\partial \Omega} \psi d S\right|.
> \end{aligned}
> $$

(Here $\operatorname{div}_{T} \nabla_{T}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami Operator.)